Why $E$ shold be open in Baby Rudin theorem 9.19

I didn't understand why $E$ should be open or what part of the proof it is used
Theorem 5.19 is

If $f$ is a continuous function from $[a,b]$ to $R^k$ and $f$ is differentiable in $(a,b)$ then $\left|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right|\leq |f'(c)|\,\,\text{for some $c\in(a,b)$}.$


Rudin needs an open domain for the definition of $f'(x)$.

because $f'(x)$ is defined only for $x$ in the interior of $E$. So to have $f'$ defined on all $E$, the set must be open.
